# Local file open URL with Href

Tags: html, localhost

I have a file .html on my computer (Local) i just want to have a Button or a HyperLink.

So I do something Like this:

Hyperlink:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">test</a>
```

Button:

```
<button href="www.google.com">test</button>
```

But it don't work because this open Url like:
file:///C:/Users/Cyril/Documents/visual%20studio%202013/Projects/MyProject/www.google.com

How can i do to open just www.google.com ?

Thank's for help

Comment: add `http://` infront of `www.google.com`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `http` before the url address in your `src` attribute. Rather than `www.google.com` you should have `http://www.google.com`

Correct hyperlink:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">test</a>
```

Comment: Glad you found my answer helpful. It would be great if you could accept my answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: I will do it, need to wait 7min !